# Axis2 WS consumer in WebMethods8.2

Tags: java, apache-axis, webservice-client, webmethods

I've got into a scenario where I have to get an Axis2 based ws consumer working within WebMethods as a java service. I've implemented the ws consumer first in netbeans just to see if it works and thus i found that the minimal amount of jars I'll require are the following:

> [ xmlschema-1.4.7.jar, apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar,
>   axiom-api-1.2.13.jar, axiom-impl-1.2.13.jar, axis2-adb-1.6.2.jar,
>   axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar, axis2-transport-http-1.6.2.jar,
>   axis2-transport-local-1.6.2.jar, commons-codec-1.3.jar,
>   commons-httpclient-3.1.jar, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar,
>   httpcore-4.0.jar, mail-1.4.jar, neethi-3.0.2.jar, wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar ]

I've uploaded these jar files under the IS/packages/{package_name}/code/jars folder. Whenever I try to execute the java service that would send the request and process the response I get the following exception:

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException:
>   org.apache.axiom.om.OMFactory.getMetaFactory()Lorg/apache/axiom/om/OMMetaFactory;

From the IS error log file I found that the actual error message is as follows:

> org.apache.axiom.om.OMFactory.getMetaFactory()Lorg/apache/axiom/om/OMMetaFactory;
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null Caused
>   by:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.apache.axiom.om.OMFactory.getMetaFactory()Lorg/apache/axiom/om/OMMetaFactory;

The platform is WebMethods 8.2 under Linux environment. The JDK version is 1.6.0_32 and the application server under WebMethods is Jetty.

Comment: Look like your code compilation in netbeans used different axiom jars different from your deployment environment. So please do check your class path for deployment env and netbeans are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the solve of this problem was a bit more tricky. First of all I manually had to configure the manifest file of the package on the IS server to use the jars provided in the package abnd thus it wouldn't get in conflict with the Axis used by the IS itself. On the other hand I had to manually add the ClassLoader because WebMethods can't use META-INF based information from jar files as it seems. To solve this problem simply use:

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.axiom.om.OMMetaFactory", "org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.factory.OMLinkedListMetaFactory");
```

That solves all the problems.